# Entity Framework code first join 3 tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

I have my 3 classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // all the default ApplicationUser properties etc...
    public virtual ICollection<UserShips> UserShips { get; set; }
    // other properties ...
}

public class Ship
{
    public int ShipId {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserShips> UserShips { get; set; }
    // other ship properties
}
```

This ship table already has data inserted into the table that is static and cannot be altered by the user only accessed

```
public class UserShips 
{
    public int UserShipId {get; set;}
    public int ShipId {get; set;}
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser {get; set;}
    public virtual Ship Ship {get; set;}
}
```

So this is what I have so far, I have tried a few different entity mappings using the Fluent API with no success.

What I'm trying to achieve is: each user can have many userships and each userships can have one shipsid (based on entry in database) and a userid, can anyone help me with my dilemma? More than happy to post any more information you need!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use DataAnnotations, you can try giving this a try (you never mentioned in the post the solution *had* to use Fluent Mappings).

```
[Table("user")]
public class User
{
[Key,Column("id")]
public string Id {get; set;
[ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
public virtual ICollection<UserShips> UserShips { get; set; }
// other properties ...
}

[Table("ship")]
public class Ship
{
[Key, Column("shipid")]
public int ShipId {get; set;}
[ForeignKey(nameof(ShipId))]
public virtual ICollection<UserShips> UserShips { get; set; }
// other ship properties
}

[Table("userships")]
public class UserShips 
{
[Key,Column("usershipid")]
public int UserShipId {get; set;}
[Column("shipid")]
public int ShipId {get; set;}
[Column("id")]
public string Id {get; set;}
[ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
public virtual User User {get; set;}
[ForeignKey(nameof(ShipId))]
public virtual Ship Ship {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!, i tried your code with no success, i ran into a error when adding data annotations to the ApplicationUser class, error on my behalf as the above code was wrong that i supplied in the first place, any further help would be much appreciated